# What are available and meaningful solutions for storing secrets suitable for Azure Container Instance?

Tags: c#, azure, docker

**What are available, meaningful (*secure, easy to store/use*) solutions for storing secrets that can be used by the instances of Docker containers hosted in Azure Container Instance?**

Easy to store/use definition:

- Use of environmental variable to access vault secrets directly.
- Automated setup of secrets from PowerShell that can be easily modified for another app.

### Context

I'm building an app - the .NET Core 3.x background service hosted in Azure Container Instance. It is a pilot project for a new line of development in my company. We have a 3rd party solution for storing secrets outside code repository. It's used by all members of Dev team. This solution produce per-user and per-machine dependency which are unnecessarily complicated for use in Docker images.

### Investigated solutions:

#### Azure Key Vault

I spent half day with reading about Azure Key Vault. I've read some tutorials about using it and how to setup the vault and authorize the app. Honestly, I was quite lost. I wasn't able to make a decision if this is a suitable solution for our needs.

Comment: How are you starting the containers, could they be started by an Azure Function on say a timer or http trigger?

Comment: AzureCLI in Azure DevOps pipeline over master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in responding.

I would suggest using the [Key Vault task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops) to get the secrets as build environment variables then in the CLI script when you create the container pass the secrets in as [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables) then your .Net Core app can simply get them from the environment.

There is also a [labs](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurekeyvault/) on this too if that helps

Comment: Thx, no matter delay. :) An interesting solution. I will investigate it ASAP.